# Join Multiple R Rastervis levelplots

Tags: r, raster, rastervis

I have two rasterstacks, each with a common legend, that I want to put on a single plot with a space in between stacks. I want the raster images to be the same size within each block and across blocks. Is there an easy way to do this using `Rastervis::levelplot`. I believe the best way is too add a legend to `grid.arrange` object, as in this MWE

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
s <- stack(
raster( matrix(runif(9),3,3)),
raster( matrix(runif(9),3,3)) )

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
levelplot(s, colorkey=FALSE, at=seq(0,1,length.out=11)),
levelplot(s, at=seq(0,1,length.out=11)),
ncol=2)
```

An even simpler solution would be to do this from within a single leveplot call

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
levObj <- levelplot(s)
comb_levObj <- c(levObj, levObj, layout = c(4, 1), merge.legends = F)
print(comb_levObj)
```

[image]

But, a simpler solution would be:

```
s <- stack(s,s)
levelplot(s)
```

[image]

Comment: These solutions don't preserve the spacing between stacks I want.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. A suggestion to visually separate the stacks would be to use `levelplot(s, layout = c(2,2))`