# How do I get coordinates in all subplots when using stacking levelplots?

Tags: r

I want to levelplot 4 rasters with a common legend. I'm using the following as a guide : [solution I'm referring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809042/join-multiple-r-rastervis-levelplots). However in this example and many more with similar techniques, all the subplots don't have the longitude and latitude numbers?
Is there any way to achieve consistency in all the subplots?